# (ab)using Django form wizard to do my bidding- is this even possible?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-formwizard

I've been charging head-first against a brick wall for days now, it's time to ask people who are smarter and more experienced than I for advice.

**Context:** As part of my web app I'm building a quiz application where users can answer quizzes consisting of multiple choice questions. The questions are all user generated so I have a couple of interesting problems at the same time:

a) I have to construct the quiz-question form(radioselect widget) dynamically on the fly. Since both the answer options and the question text are user-generated (models 'Question' and 'Answer'), I have to run a query in the view and then pass the variables to my form's init. That way I can populate the choices and overwrite the label with the question text:

**from forms.py:**

```
#it's not very clean, there's a lot of legacy code in there...
class AnsweredQuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = AnsweredQuestion
        widget = {
            'id': forms.TextInput,  # needed for formset that I was using
        }

    question_field = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        empty_label='Gee, this is tough. Can you show me some hints?',
        widget=forms.RadioSelect,
        queryset=Question.objects.all(),
        required=True,
        help_text='',
        error_messages={'required': 'Please pick an answer'},
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):  # I'm using django crispy-forms
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_method = 'POST'
        self.helper.form_id = ''
        self.helper.form_class = ''
        self.helper.form_action = ''
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.help_text_inline = True
        self.helper.render_unmentioned_fields = False
        self.helper.form_error_title = 'Form Errors'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('question_field'),
            Field('id', css_class='hidden'),
        )
        self.question = kwargs.pop('question', None)
        super(AnsweredQuestionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['question_field'].label = self.question.question_text
        self.fields['question_field'].queryset = self.question.answers.all()
```

b) That means that the quiz-question forms are modelforms (I have a model called 'AnsweredQuestions' that saves instances of given answers. There's also a model 'TakenQuiz' for the quiz). I create an instance of TakenQuiz when a user starts a quiz and of AnsweredQuestion when she answers a quiz-question and the form gets saved.

**from models.py**

```
class AnsweredQuestion(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, null=True, blank=True)
    given_answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer, null=True, blank=True)
    taken_quiz = models.ForeignKey(TakenQuiz, related_name="answered_questions", null=True, blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    correct = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'answered question'
        verbose_name_plural = 'answered questions'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ On save, update timestamp."""
        if not self.id:
            self.date = datetime.datetime.now()
        super(AnsweredQuestion, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.given_answer)
```

**from views.py(test view):**

```
def take_quiz(request, category_slug, course_slug, module_slug, quiz_number):
    user = request.user
    category = Category.objects.get(slug=category_slug)
    course = Course.objects.get(category=category, slug=course_slug)
    module = Module.objects.get(course=course, slug=module_slug)
    quiz = module.quizzes.get(number=quiz_number)
    quiz_questions = Question.objects.filter(quiz=quiz)
    ...
    else:
        taken_quiz = TakenQuiz()
        aq_form = AnsweredQuestionForm(question=question)
```

c) a quiz can consist of a variable number of quiz-questions, I only set a max limit. So pretty much everything is dynamic :(

So here are my specific questions:

1. How can I access the URL params and use them for my queries if I'm using a formwizard? (btw, I hate class-based generic views for that) I tried to make the number of questions dynamic, but haven't figured out yet how exactly I can pass the variable (len(quiz_questions) to the wizard... My url looks like the following, and unfortunately I need to pass all of it either to the template context or to the forms' init:

   **from urls.py:**

   ```
   url(r'^(?P<category_slug>[-\w]+)/(?P<course_slug>[-\w]+)/(?P<module_slug>[-\w]+)/(?P<quiz_number>\d+)/$', quiz_wizard, name='quiz_wizard'),
   quiz_wizard = QuizWizard.as_view(named_quiz_forms)
   named_quiz_forms = [('quiz_question_%d' % i, AnsweredQuestionForm) for i in xrange(0, len(quiz_questions))]
   ```
2. Should I even bother to try to bend the formwizard to do what I need? I've spent a lot of time on google research and the source code, and I found potential solutions for some of the problems, but not for all. Especially not for all of them at the same time...

   **I would probably have to overwrite at least all of these:**

   ```
   class QuizWizard(NamedUrlSessionWizardView):

       def get_form(self, step=None, data=None, files=None):
           form = super(QuizWizard, self).get_form(step, data, files)
           ...
           return form

       def get_form_kwargs(self, step):
           return {}

       def get_form_instance(self, step):
           return self.instance_dict.get(step, None)
   ```
3. And finally: Any recommendation how I should handle the quizzes if I can't use the formwizard? Using the formwizard just seemed... cleaner to me vs just using views for every single quiz-question. The big advantages of the wizard are that I don't have to take care of saving the form data somewhere until the whole quiz is completed and validated and that the wizard keeps track of the number of steps and the current step for me. I'm a newbie and not really all that great at writing this kind of advanced stuff from scratch.

**Thanks a lot for your help, any advice or help is highly appreciated!!**

Comment: Can you post your full code for AnsweredQuestionForm?

Comment: No problemo, I've added AnsweredQuestionForm and the AnsweredQuestion model. Let me know if you need anything else. And thanks again Danny!

Comment: Your code looks complicated. Check out https://github.com/myles/django-quiz. The code looks simpler.

Comment: I'll check it out, maybe I can use some parts of it!

Comment: I don't think something that hasn't been updated in over 4 years will be very valuable.